# Парсер сайта на Python через BS

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

друзья
Парсю я значит сайт используя Питон, через BS и requests, никого не трогаю
Но потом замечаю что при выводе всего кода страницы, отсутствует значительная его часть. В коде страницы она отображается, но суп её почему то не видит.
Как мне её спарсить?

вот пример

```html
<div class="oaserecommendation section similar" data-recommendation-oase="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;similar&quot;,&quot;shopID&quot;:&quot;CQ_DE_B2C&quot;, &quot;headline&quot;: &quot;Unsere Kunden hatten auch Interesse an&quot;, &quot;pageType&quot;: &quot;Product Details&quot;}">
  <span class="recommendation-headline">Unsere Kunden hatten auch Interesse an</span>
  <div class="gallery gallery-js-ready autorotation-disabled" data-desktop="1" data-tablet="1" data-mobile="1">
    <div class="ccpProductSlideset ccpProductSlideset--square ccpProductSlideset--slides-10" data-slideset="">
      <div class="ccpProductSlideset__stage" data-slideset-stage="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Первый div выводится, span тоже, а потом получаю кучу пустых тэгов, при попытке получить их содержимое функцией .contents[], естественно выдаёт None

Comment: 1. Покажите, как Вы парсите. 2. Возможно, это содержимое появляется в результате работы js, так что получить его через `requests` Вы не сможете.

Comment: Скорей всего это результат работы js, использовать другую библиотеку? К примеру Selenium подойдёт для этих целей?

Comment: @Dmitry подойдёт. Но вы бы ссылку предоставили. Может, вы просто неверно обрабатываете хтмл, нужно посмотреть.

Comment: https://www.conrad.de/de/raspberry-pi-gehaeuse-aluminium-gehaeuse-b-2-b-3-b-raspberry-pi-2-b-raspberry-pi-3-b-raspberry-pi-3-b-raspber-1460816.html?sc.ref=Product%20Details

Comment: Блоки товаров, которые называются Unsere Kunden hatten auch Interesse an и Unsere Kunden kauften auch не парсятся